# Produce tikz image with multiple maps

Tags: pgfplotstable, getmap

I am struggling with this one for some time now and failed to find a straight answer.

I have several maps to display within `tikz` environment with use of `getmap` package. The data on map locations (street, town, country) are stored in `.dat` files so I use `pgfplotstablegetelem` to read a location and store it as a new definition. Then the stored parameters are used to feed `drawMapE` command that is supposed to produce map.

The problem is that I can't find a way to feed `getmap` properly. Instead of having names of towns, streets and countries in a produced URL, all I have are names of variables.

The file contains couple of columns, among them country, town, street, abbr.

I appreciate your help with this one.

Please take a look at this MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[overwrite=true,mode=gm]{getmap}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,decorations.pathmorphing,calc,external,fadings}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\newcommand{\drawMapE}[6]{
\getmap[file=img/#1,
overwrite=true,
    color=blue,
    xsize=600,
    ysize=600,
    zoom=16,
    scale=2,
    markers={&markers=size:mid|color:green|#2},
    visible={#3},
]{}
   \node at (#4,#5) {\includegraphics[width=#6cm]{img/#1}};
}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma,header=has colnames]{table/places.dat}{\datawhead}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\W{40}
\pgfmathsetmacro\H{40}
\pgfmathsetmacro\R{10}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (\W,\H);
\foreach \a/\i in {0/1,30/2}{
   \pgfmathsetmacro\x{\W/2+\R*cos(\a)}
   \pgfmathsetmacro\y{\H/2+\R*sin(\a)}
   \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{street}\of{\datawhead}
   \edef\street{\expandafter\pgfplotsretval}
   \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{town}\of{\datawhead}
   \edef\town{\pgfplotsretval}
   \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{country}\of{\datawhead}
   \edef\country{\pgfplotsretval}
   \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{abbr}\of{\datawhead}
   \def\fileName{\pgfplotsretval}

   \drawMapE{\fileName}{\street,\town,\country}{}{\x}{\y}{5}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In this example suppose to produce two maps with different contents (two different addresses) R distance from the middle. Here the address is automatically changed to the default one due to a fault url. Sample of the log file:

```
PGFPlots: reading {table/places.dat}
Package getmap Info: using latin1 encoding on input line 47.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-iso-8859-1.def
File: se-iso-8859-1.def 2016/05/16 v1.11 stringenc: ISO-8859-1
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-utf8.def
File: se-utf8.def 2016/05/16 v1.11 stringenc: UTF-8
)
runsystem(getmapdl  -l "" -m gm -x 600 -y 600 -z 16 -s 2 -t roadmap -i  png -c "
blue" -n 1 -L "en" -M "&markers=size:mid|color:green|\street ,\town ,\country "
 -C "" -P "" -p "" -V "" -o img/kaart6c)...executed.
```

The code produces the following picture: 
[image: two maps with R distance from the middle]

places.dat contains the following:

```
abbr,street,town,country,month,year
arne5,Arne Ulstrups vei 4,H{\o}vik,Norway,October,2008
```

Comment: Could you add a sketch of what you want to achieve? I'm having a bit of a struggle, what the output is supposed to look like.

Comment: Hello @naphaneal, I have updated my request with the pic.

Comment: to be clear: you want multiple different maps in one picture?
so far your code produces one image from one map multiple times.

Comment: More explanation is available now.

Comment: Could you add the content of `places.dat` as well? (Replace with random places if you like, just with the correct structure.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. it has been updated.

Comment: Is there anybody who tried to solve this problem?

Comment: I found this thread in a German forum, which shows a similar problem to yours. link to forum: https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/7134/getmap-und-datatool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have visited [German forum](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/7134/getmap-und-datatool) suggested by @naphaneal and found some useful information, thank you for that! First it seems that one needs to use [datatool](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool) package to feed \getmap command with proper location address by using \expandonce. This together with [pgf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) commands solves the problem I was having.

One remark: I had about 12 maps to put into my image and once I compiled tex file not all of the maps were fetched, three were empty files. In this situation one deletes the empty .png files and recompile with option overwrite set to false for \getmap command.

```
overwrite=false
```

Usually one attempt is enough to fetch the missing files. The full working code:

```
\documentclass[margin=0pt,crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage[mode=gm]{getmap}

\begin{document}

\DTLsetseparator{,}
\DTLloaddb{places}{table/places.dat}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathsetmacro\W{40}
\pgfmathsetmacro\H{40}
\pgfmathsetmacro\R{15}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (\W,\H);
\draw (0,0) rectangle (\W,\H);   

\DTLforeach*{places}{\street=street,\town=town, \country=country,\abbr=abbr}{%
    \begingroup
    \edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\getmap[
        file=img/\abbr,%
        overwrite=false,
        color=blue,
        xsize=600,
        ysize=600,
        zoom=16,
        scale=2
        ]{%
            \expandonce\street, \expandonce\town, \expandonce\country%
         }%
     }\x
     \pgfmathsetmacro\xi{0.5*\W+\R*cos(\DTLcurrentindex*30)}
     \pgfmathsetmacro\yi{0.5*\H+\R*sin(\DTLcurrentindex*30)}

     \node[anchor=center,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] at (\xi,\yi) {\includegraphics[width=8cm]{img/\abbr}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Example of the places.dat file:

```
abbr,street,town,country,month,year
arne5,Arne Ulstrups vei 4,H{\o}vik,Norway,October,2008
```